# Will cooling off the condenser coil improve the efficiency of a domestic refrigerator?

Tags: thermodynamics

Will cooling off the condenser coil improve the efficiency of a domestic refrigerator, based on R134a? If so, what is the lowest ambient temperature the condenser can take, for the system to still work?

My idea is to rewire a standard refrigerator, and put the condenser coil outdoors, while keeping the evaporator and the box indoors. Outdoor temperature where I live varies between +25C and -20C.

Comment: That is a good idea! But I do not know how to calculate the efficiency improvement.

Comment: How far will the refrigerator be from where the relocated coil piping will enter the house?

Comment: @Not_Einstein The refrigerator will be on a wall, and the condenser will be on the other side of that wall, so the coil will only be moved approx 40 cm (i.e. 80 cm longer piping in total.

Comment: This sounds like an HVAC engineering question.

Answer (score 1):

Having a cooler condenser coil would improve efficiency. I do not think too low of an ambient temperature will be a problem, I could not find the freezing point of r134a, but its boiling point at 1 atmosphere is -26.3 degrees C so I don't think you will have a problem.